# Sprite loses quality when converted to texture in unity

Tags: unity, 2d, textures

So I have a sprite that is 750 (width) by 210 (height). I have put it in the game and adjusted the pixels per unit to match the scene size. But soon I realized that I need to use a texture to make the sprite appear to be scrolling.

When I did this I noticed a loss in quality when I made a quad and applied the texture to it. It seems that the sprite changes resolution when I make it a texture. It goes from (750px x 210px) to (512px x 256px) as seen in pic below:

As a sprite:

[image]

As a Texture:

[image]

I am a complete beginner to unity and need all the help I can get.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the DXT1 compression settings after you changed it to a texture. Try using TrueColour or Automatic TrueColour option in the inspector, which will maintain the image quality. But it will also require more space

Answer (score 1):

all textures in Unity are expanded into a power of 2 square. So your texture would be expanded to 1024x1024, which will cause ugly effects.

You should modify the texture into 1024x256, for example, so it expands cleanly to 1024x1024.

Comment: You can also disable rescaling the texture by setting the texture type to "Advanced" and changing the "Non Power of Two" parameter to "None." Also, it's not true that textures are expanded to a square — you can see in the asker's example that Unity can choose a different power of two on each axis.